# How to define this restriction in PuLP?

Tags: pulp

I am working on a ILP to allocate optimally invoices to funds, so my decision variable is binary X_ij, for i in invoices, j in funds.

Each invoice is from a specific payer, and some funds have restrictions on the amount of money that can be allocated to payers.

Particularly, the restriction im struggling with is the following:

The sum of money allocated to a fund from the 10 payers with more money allocated to that fund cannot pass certain limit.

So, I created a new variable w_pj : money allocated to payer p from fund j (that depends on x_ij)

What the restriction says is that if I sort w_pj for a fixed j, the sum of the top 10 values of w_pj should not pass M (a big constant).

I am struggling to define this because even if a define a sorting function that uses >= instead of >, when I define the restriction PuLP says that w’s are NoneType, and it makes sense because it has not yet solved and hence does not know the value of w_pj when defining the restriction.

So I am wondering, is there a way to define a restriction of this type?

As I couldn't sort the values of w for every fund, I tried a very inefficient way:

sum of all possible combinations of 10 w’s should satisfy the restriction,

but if I have 90 payers then this results in ~ 4000000000